# vim sometimes displays full path of file instead of just the filename?

Tags: vim

This may seem a little nit-picky, but I like using the wildmenu to switch between buffers: I do `:b` and then hit tab until I get to the file I want. The problem is that sometimes, vim shows the entire file path instead of just the file. So instead of getting something nice like

```
foo.cpp bar.cpp foobar.cpp
```

I get

```
foo.cpp ~/Documents/programming/projects/my_project/src/bar.cpp foobar.cpp
```

Which ANNOYS THE HELL out of me. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. Deleting the buffer and reopening the file doesn't do anything; I have to restart vim in order for it to go away.

Does anyone know why vim does this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on vim's working directory. You can track / print it with `:pwd` or with `:echo getcwd()`, or change it with `:cd`. Vim will try to shorten path when you tab through buffers.

I recommend typing some more letters that uniquely identify the buffer you want, e. g. try `:b foo.c` or `:b o.c` or even `:b o.` for `foo.cpp`. You can still use tab in order to find your buffer.

What I also sometimes do is automatically switch to the buffer directory:

```
:set autochdir
```

I'm not sure whether that helps you solve your problem though.

Comment: There's also `:set autochdir` built-in; it does the same as your `:autocmd` (and better).